# The simplest formula to calculate page count?

Tags: c#, pagination

I have an array and I want to divide them into page according to preset page size.

This is how I do:

```
private int CalcPagesCount()
{
    int  totalPage = imagesFound.Length / PageSize;

    // add the last page, ugly
    if (imagesFound.Length % PageSize != 0) totalPage++;
    return totalPage;
}
```

I feel the calculation is not the simplest (I am poor in math), can you give one simpler calculation formula?

Comment: imo, what feels "ugly" is not the fact that u have an "if", but the fact that your firstly calculated "totalPage" is not the actual total number of pages, and u have to "patch" it in a complementary calculus. See my answer below which only adds semantic code.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Force it to round up:

```
totalPage = (imagesFound.Length + PageSize - 1) / PageSize;
```

Or use floating point math:

```
totalPage = (int) Math.Ceiling((double) imagesFound.Length / PageSize);
```

Comment: Danger ... this results in an overflow when `PageSize = int.MaxValue`.  I added an answer that's not vulnerable to an overflow.

Comment: To avoid the overflow you could just refactor the formula to get: `((imagesFound.Length - 1) / PageSize) + 1`

Answer (score 35):

NOTE: you will always get at least 1 page, even for 0 count, if the page size is > 1, which is what I needed but may not be what you need. A page size of 1(silly but technically valid) and a count of 0 would be zero pages. Depending on your needs you may want to check for a zero value for count & page size of 1

```
int pages = ((count - 1) / PAGESIZE) + 1;
```

Comment: Yes, simpler. Simpler but Wrong.
if count = 0 then pages = 1

Comment: @Pevel Melnikov . I suppose in a purely pedantic sense it is wrong, but it depends on context. In the code I used this in I always wanted at least 1 page (0 pages was invalid even if there were 0 items). I should at least add a note.

Comment: @PavelMelnikov, it's not exactly wrong.  Just depends on how you want to look at it.  The assumption that it always returns at least 1 page is incorrect, though.  0 records and a page size of 1 will result in 0.  So just either not allow a page size of 0 or do a check.

Answer (score 24):

Actually, you are close to the best you can do.  About the only thing that I can think of that might be "better" is something like this:

```
totalPage = (imagesFound.Length + PageSize - 1) / PageSize;
```

And the only reason that this is any better is that you avoid the if statement.

Comment: Danger ... this results in an overflow when `PageSize = int.MaxValue`.  I added an answer that's not vulnerable to an overflow.

Answer (score 13):

The OP contains a valid answer.  If I wanted to *turn off* paging then I could set `PageSize = int.MaxValue`.

Several answers here add to `PageSize` (`imagesFound.Length + PageSize`) and that could cause an overflow.  Which then leads to an incorrect result.

This is the code I am going to use:

```
int imageCount = imagesFound.Length;

// include this if when you always want at least 1 page 
if (imageCount == 0)
{
    return 1;
}

return imageCount % PageSize != 0 
    ? imageCount / PageSize + 1 
    : imageCount / PageSize;
```

Comment: Or use something like my answer to avoid all the clutter to essentially be doing the same thing here. single line of code that calculates this exact multi-conditional statement.

Answer (score 7):

Always used this formula:

```
int totalPages = items.Count / pageSize + (items.Count % pageSize > 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var pageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)_collection.Count / (float)_itemsPerPage);
```

**Explanation:**

Divide the **number of items in the collection** by the **items per page**. Then use Math.Ceiling to round this number up to the nearest integer.

e.g. 7 Items in the 'Book' / 3 items per page = 2.33. 2.33 rounded up to the nearest int = 3.

Answer (score 2):

just semantic code, which makes explicit the partial result, and makes it obvious for any reader what is calculated. I prefer this to the compact formula :

```java
    private int calculateNbPages(int nbResults, int pageSize)
        {
            int  nbFullyFilledPages = nbResults / pageSize;
            int nbPartiallyFilledPages = (nbResults % pageSize == 0) ? 0 : 1;
            
            return nbFullyFilledPages + nbPartiallyFilledPages;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having errors with page numbering the best way I can think of calculating noOfPages is by doing the following line

```
totalPage = Math.Ceiling(imagesFound.Length / PageSize);
```

This should not give you page 2 when PageSize == imagesFound.Length

Comment: I don't think this is valid. If you have a length of 3 and a pagesize of 2, you would expect 2 pages (first page has 2 items, second page has 1). Doing this will give you (3-1)/2 = 1 page.

Comment: Altered the original post to accommodate for that aswell, thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1):

1. You Can Get Total Page in Sql Server:-

```
DECLARE @PageCount INT;
DECLARE @NoOfData INT;
SET @NoOfData = (select Count(*) AS [PageCount] from YourTableName)
SET @PageCount=((@NoOfData+@PageSize-1)/@PageSize)
SELECT @PageCount AS [PageCount]
```

2. You Can get in your code-

```
int totalPage = (int) Math.Ceiling((double) imagesFound.Length / PageSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me:

```
if(totalRecords%value === 0){
  count = (totalRecords) / value;
}
else {
  count = Math.floor((totalRecords + value - 1) / value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I wrote myself:

```
private int GetPageCount(int count, int pageSize)
{
    int result = 0;

    if(count > 0)
    {
        result = count / pageSize;
        if(result > 0 && (count > (pageSize * result)))
        {
           result++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

(And sure, don't set `pageSize` to `int.MaxValue`)

Answer (score 0):

Below is working code to calculate pagination in List:

```
              int i = 0;
              int pagecount = 0;
              int pageSize = 50;
```

List Items= new List ();
To do : Add items in List:

```
              if (Items.Count() != 0)
              {
                    int pageNumber = Total Records / 50;

                          for (int num = 0; numi < pageNumber; num++)
                          {
                                var x = Items.Skip(i * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
                                i++;
                          }

                    var y = Items.Skip(i * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the function below. It does not use floating point calculation, so it is faster than some other solutions I have seen.

```
int GetPageCount()
{
    //when pageSize is 0, return all records on one page
    return (pageSize != 0) ? (recordCount / pageSize + Math.Sign(recordCount % pageSize)) : 1;
}
```